# Git not updating

Tags: git

Git id not updating the files in the branch when I use Pull. But when I compare the file with Latest Repository difference , I can see that the file has been updated. I also tried to do this command prompt. Doesnt work.
The update was working fine until yesterday. 
How can I fix this ?

Comment: Some files are not updating, really.

Comment: Really, if you don't add the output of the pull or any we could work with, no one can diagnose your problem.

Comment: It says All files up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git reset --hard
```

This will reset your repo so you can pull again

Comment: You could add a warning like "**Any change you may have done on your local copy will be lost forever**"

Comment: So I just lost everything I guess. Grr, its gonna be long night

Comment: That's why I always make a backup of my repo when something is not right with git :P

Comment: And for backing up you could simply create a new branch and commit on it. Or stash your changes.