# VS Code devcontainer: git extension UI not updating, file watcher does not watch .git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

Short description:

Inside a devcontainer, the git UI does not update even though `git.autorefresh: true`
is set. Outside the devcontainer it works without problems. Maybe related to this stack overflow question [git not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647055/git-not-updating)

My system:

- Windows 10 Pro version 10.0.19045 build 19045
- VS Code 1.80.2 (only extension not preinstalled is Dev Containers from Microsoft)
- git version 2.28.0.windows.1
- Extension ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers v0.304.0

Workflow:

In windows I clone (git bash terminal) a repository. I open this repository in VS Code. I add my `devcontainer.json` file and my `docker-compose.yml`. I use the terminal in VS Code (cmd) and use
`git add .` --> afterwards I see in the git add on that the two files are moved from changes to staged changes.
`git commit -m "add devcontainer files"` --> afterwards I see in the git extension that there are no more changes and I can now synchronize or publish.
Now I use the command `Dev Containers: Reopen in Container` in VS Code.
Now I add a new file `first.py` here using `touch first.py`.
This is shown in the git extension UI under `Changes`.
I use the terminal (bash) and write `git add .`
Now the file does not go to `Staged Changes` but stays in `Changes`. This happens even if I run `git commit -m "add first.py"`. The git extension does not show any changes. Only when I explicitly click on the small refresh symbol it is updated.

devcontainer.json:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "dockerComposeFile": [
        "../docker-compose.yml",
        "docker-compose.yml"
    ],
    "service": "testservice",
    "workspaceFolder": "/var/www/html"
}
```

Expected behavior:

Just like locally, I expect the git addon inside the devcontainer to recognize my changes via terminal.

Already tried solution steps (followed by rebuild container):

1. Settings `git.autorefresh: true` set
2. reinstalled VS code + extension
3. Set logging to trace and checked output of Git. Here it is noticeable that locally, after I run e.g.
    `git add .`, the following shows in the log:
   2

```
023-08-08 09:17:29.169 [debug] [.git] Change: c:\projects\test_git_problems\.git\index
2023-08-08 09:17:30.172 [trace] Operation start: Status (blocking: false, readOnly: false; retry: false; showProgress: true)
2023-08-08 09:17:30.244 [info] > git config --get commit.template [69ms]
2023-08-08 09:17:30.248 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) --ignore-case refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master [71ms]
2023-08-08 09:17:30.289 [trace] Operation start: GetObjectDetails (blocking: false, readOnly: true; retry: false; showProgress: false)
2023-08-08 09:17:30.321 [info] > git status -z -uall [70ms]
```

Inside the devcontainer nothing happens in the output of git with logging level trace.

Afterwards I looked under `Help --> Toggle Developer Tools`. There I filtered on 'File Watcher' under console. In the devcontainer I see the following:
T

```
RACE [File Watcher (node.js)] [raw] ["change"] globalStorage
log.ts:401 TRACE [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
log.ts:401 TRACE [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [CHANGED] c:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
```

While locally I see the following:

```
TRACE [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\projects\test_git_problems\.git\index
log.ts:401 TRACE [File Watcher (node.js)] >> ignored (not included) c:\projects\test_git_problems\.git\index
log.ts:401 TRACE [File Watcher (parcel)] >> normalized [DELETED] c:\projects\test_git_problems\.git\index.lock
log.ts:401 TRACE [File Watcher (parcel)] >> normalized [CHANGED] c:\projects\test_git_problems\.git\index
```

This gave me the following ideas:

1. Line Endings EOL set to LF
2. `chmod -R 777 .git` executed

Unfortunately also without success.

My test repo also contains only 5 files, so I maximum number of file watchers should not be a problem. Using
`cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`
I get: 524288

Other tested / found out:

When I create a folder inside the devcontainer and run `git init`, the git addon works as desired. Therefore I suspect it could be due to Windows.